# How to launch a Bottle application over a CherryPy standalone web server?

Tags: python, cherrypy, bottle

I have a python web app developed using the bottle framework. My bottle app is web API that provide methods that return JSon data, so no static content is needed. I am trying to deploy it to production using a CherryPy server which is supposed to be robust for production applications.

My web_api.py file (my bottle app) looks something like this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/stuff')
def do_stuff():
    '''
    Method that does stuff.
    '''
    stuff = {'data': 'some data'}
    # Return the environment info as Json data
    return stuff
```

I have a server.py file to launch the Bottle app over the CherryPy server that looks like this:

```
from my_package.web_api import app
from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer

server = CherryPyWSGIServer(
    ('0.0.0.0', 80),
    app,
    server_name='My_App',
    numthreads=30)

server.start()
```

so when I run my server using this command:

```
python server.py
```

My server is successfully started and start listening in port 80 as expected. However once I start my web server I cannot stop it any more. I have tried Ctrl + C which works with the development server but has no effect here. Am I starting the server the right way? How do I stop it once it is running? Is this the correct way to launch a Bottle app over CherryPy?

BTW, I am running python 2.7 in Windows 8.

Comment: Anyone looking at this question now (2017) should be advised that this will not work in recent versions of CherryPy. [Since version 9.0.0](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/history.html) (Jan 2017), cherrypy.wsgiserver moved to [Cheroot](https://pypi.org/project/Cheroot/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is correct, you just need to add a try/catch statement:

```
from my_package.web_api import app
from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer

server = CherryPyWSGIServer(
    ('0.0.0.0', 80),
    app,
    server_name='My_App',
    numthreads=30)

try:
    server.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop()
```

You might wanna also consider to do some logging with [wsgi-request-logger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgi-request-logger/) or something similar.

This are three alternative ways on hosting a WSGI application within cherrypy:

```
import cherrypy as cp
from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
from cherrypy.process.servers import ServerAdapter


from bottle import Bottle

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/stuff')
def do_stuff():
    '''
    Method that does stuff.
    '''
    stuff = {'data': 'some dataX'}
    return stuff

def run_decoupled(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, **config):
    server = CherryPyWSGIServer((host, port), app, **config)
    try:
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()

def run_in_cp_tree(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, **config):
    cp.tree.graft(app, '/')
    cp.config.update(config)
    cp.config.update({
        'server.socket_port': port,
        'server.socket_host': host
    })
    cp.engine.signals.subscribe() # optional
    cp.engine.start()
    cp.engine.block()

def run_with_adapter(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, config=None, **kwargs):
    cp.server.unsubscribe()
    bind_addr = (host, port)
    cp.server = ServerAdapter(cp.engine,
                              CherryPyWSGIServer(bind_addr, app, **kwargs),
                              bind_addr).subscribe()
    if config:
        cp.config.update(config)
    cp.engine.signals.subscribe() # optional
    cp.engine.start()
    cp.engine.block()
```

The `run_in_cp_tree` and `run_with_adapter` functions are using the cherrypy engine, which enables the use of [plugins](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html#module-cherrypy.process.plugins) to have off-the-shelf auto-reload, pidfile, daemonization, signal management and some more goodies, along with the possibility to create one of your own.

Notice that you can also use the [WSGIPathInfoDispatcher](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.wsgiserver.html#module-cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver3) to attach multiple wsgi applications on the CherryPyWSGIServer.

Comment: Wow! Great answer @cyraxjoe, thanks a lot! I spend all day looking for this info with no luck. Thanks :)

Comment: by the way @cyraxjoe, do you happen to have an example on how to use wsgi-request-logger in a setting like the one I have? using Bottle on top of CherryPy? I followed their documentation, but I am getting empty logs.

Comment: @Cas I just wrote a [blog post](http://blog.joel.mx/posts/cherrypy-as-a-wsgi-server) with a longer explanation covering the access/error log use cases. I hope that you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to connect any WSGI server to my BottlePy app here in 2019 turned out to be rather tricky(to a noobie like me).
I tried connecting several ones, spent most off my time with *CherryPy*, which has changed his syntax.

The simpliest to me turned out to be waitress https://waitress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html
After i figured out how to use it on waitress i got it in cherrypy also. So:

**CherryPy** http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=WSGi#host-a-foreign-wsgi-application-in-cherrypy

1)***add after imports***

```
import cherrypy as cp

app  = bottle.Bottle()
```

2) ***change in routes "@bottle" to "@app"***

3)***add this as main function***

```
 cp.tree.graft(app, '/')
 cp.server.start()
```

**Waitress**

1)***add after imports***

```
import waitress 

app  = bottle.Bottle()
```

2)***add this as main function***

```
 waitress.serve(app, listen='*:44100')
```

3) ***change in routes "@bottle" to  "@app"***

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do in 2024:

server.py:

```
import cherrypy as cp
import bottle_app

app = bottle_app.app

cp.tree.graft(app, '/')
cp.server.start()
```

My Bottle app is in a file called `bottle_app.py`. This file has the `import bottle` statement, all of the `@bottle.route` statements, and this at the top:

```
app = bottle.default_app()
```